# Alternatives to Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint in Unity

Tags: unity, camera, coordinates

What are alternatives to `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` in Unity?

So, here is my code (just the piece which is relevant for the question):

```
void sendPointerMove(ref Vector3 mousePosition)
{
    lastMousePosition = mousePosition;

    Vector3 mousePositionInWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    PointerData pointerData = new PointerData(
       mousePositionInWorld: mousePositionInWorld
    );
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    if (needToSendPointerMove(mousePosition))
    {
       sendPointerMove(ref mousePosition);
    }
}
```

I am using JetBrains Rider to develop for Unity. And the ide suggests me the following about my `sendPointerMove` function invocation inside the `FixedUpdate`:

> Expensive method invocation

I am sure that the issue is due to the `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` because when I comment out the part the warning disappears.

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Let's analyze this a bit deeper, and separate the process of searching for the camera (`Camera.main`) from the process of mapping the input vector (`ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition)`). Do you find the problem is improved if you cache a reference to the camera once, rather than searching for it every FixedUpdate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, when you call `Camera.main`, Unity internally uses the `FindGameObjectsWithTag` to search through all of the objects in your scene that have the 'MainCamera' tag, returning the first active one. Since this will always be slower than a direct reference to it, you should cache it. You can declare it as a member variable and then initialize it inside your Start function.

This sort of pseudo code gives an example

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{  
    Camera cam;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void ConvertMousePos()
    {
        Vector3 mousePositionInWorld = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ConvertMousePos();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's definitely slower to use `Camera.main` because it goes through every game object on the scene comparing tags until it finds one that fits.